# Json Schema, Properties as Property not working

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Maybe sounds confusing, I want to validate this model schema (should has $schema, title, properties and required field):

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "My Schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "myData": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name_1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name_2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name_3": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "myData"
  ]
}
```

I've already done this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "$schema": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "properties": {
      "type": "object",
      "enum": "myData"
    },
    "required": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "myData": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but this part is not working well:

```
"properties": {
      "type": "object",
      "enum": "myData"
 },
```

Is possible to do this? or is prohibited to use those built schema words like: "required", "enum", "properties" as a property inside "properties"?.
Thanks in advance for helping me to understand this part :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, sorry. I've created wrong the json schema, it should be like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://jsonschema.net",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "properties": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "myData": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    },
    "required": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And works fine :)